# Sanitizing words extracted from text files and writing them to a database

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, natural-language-processing

This code reads text files from some path, tokenizes, removes stop words, lowercases, removes punctuation and numbers, then writes the result to a database.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function
import os, codecs, re, string, mysql
import mysql.connector

'''Reading files with txt extension'''
y_ = ""
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/Users/Documents/source-document/part1"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            x_ = codecs.open(os.path.join(root,file),"r", "utf-8-sig")
            for lines in x_.readlines():
                y_ = y_ + lines
#print(tokenized_docs) 

'''Tokenizing sentences of the text files'''

from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
raw_docs = sent_tokenize(y_)

tokenized_docs = [sent_tokenize(y_) for sent in raw_docs]

'''Removing stop words'''

stopword_removed_sentences = []
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopset = stopwords.words("English")
for i in tokenized_docs[0]:
    tokenized_docs = ' '.join([word for word in i.split() if word not in stopset])
    stopword_removed_sentences.append(tokenized_docs)

''' Removing punctuation marks'''

regex = re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation)) 
nw = []
for review in stopword_removed_sentences:
    new_review = ''
    for token in review: 
        new_token = regex.sub(u'', token)
        if not new_token == u'':
            new_review += new_token
    nw.append(new_review)

'''Lowercasing letters after removing puctuation marks.'''

lw = []  #lw stands for lowercase word.
for i in nw:
    k = i.lower()
    lw.append(k) 

'''Removing number with a dummy symbol'''
nr = []
for j in lw:
    string = j
    regex = r'[^\[\]]+(?=\])'
# let "#" be the dummy symbol
    output = re.sub(regex,'#',string)
    nr.append(output)
nrfinal = []    
for j in nr:
    rem = 0
    outr = ''
    for i in j:
        if ord(i)>= 48 and ord(i)<=57:
            rem += 1
            if rem == 1:
                outr = outr+ '#'
        else:
             rem = 0             
             outr = outr+i
    nrfinal.append(outr)
'''Inserting into database'''
def connect():
    for j in nrfinal:
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(user = 'root', password = '', unix_socket = "/tmp/mysql.sock", database = 'Thesis' )
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO splitted_sentences(sentence_id, splitted_sentences) VALUES(%s, %s)""",(cursor.lastrowid,j))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    connect()
```

I am not getting any error with this code. Please review it for writing it in a more optimized way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Memory usage

What I notice most, is that this is bound to use a lot of memory.

First you load **all** the files (at once) into memory.

Then you copy over (with modifications) the data into another variable. And another. And another. ...

This creates a few lists, all with the same total memory size as the entire documents you have read.

Ex-pen-sive.

## Generators/Iterators to the rescue!

In Python, iterators are really nice. They allow something like continuations and just-in-time calculation. This causes memory usage to be a lot lower, on the (perhaps) extra cost of a bit more CPU processing. But... I think in this case it will overall be a saving because you have a lot less memory usage, so probably also less cache-misses.

Let's see what we can do about that.

## The last step

```
nrfinal = []    
for j in nr:
    rem = 0
    outr = ''
    for i in j:
        if ord(i)>= 48 and ord(i)<=57:
            rem += 1
            if rem == 1:
                outr = outr+ '#'
        else:
             rem = 0             
             outr = outr+i
    nrfinal.append(outr)
```

The easiest step is to first make it a function.

```
def calc_nrfinal(inp):
    retval = []
    for j in nr:
        rem = 0
        outr = ''
        for i in j:
            if ord(i)>= 48 and ord(i)<=57:
                rem += 1
                if rem == 1:
                    outr = outr+ '#'
            else:
                 rem = 0             
                 outr = outr+i
        retval.append(outr)
    return retval
nrfinal = calc_nrfinal(nr)
```

Now this does not save us memory. But by rewriting it a little bit, it will become a generator.

```
def calc_nrfinal(inp):
    for j in nr:
        rem = 0
        outr = ''
        for i in j:
            if ord(i)>= 48 and ord(i)<=57:
                rem += 1
                if rem == 1:
                    outr = outr+ '#'
            else:
                 rem = 0             
                 outr = outr+i
        yield outr
nrfinal = calc_nrfinal(nr)
```

The downside is that you can only iterate over `nrfinal` once, but you only need to do it once.

### The inner loop

One thing that bothers me is the inner loop here. `ord(i)>=49 and ord(i)<=57)` could be written as `49 <= ord(i) <= 57` (one of Pythons strengths!). But... I'd rather write

```
outr = re.sub(r'[0-9]+', '#', j)
```

Giving us

```
def calc_nrfinal(inp):
    for j in nr:
        yield re.sub(r'[0-9]+', '#', j)
nrfinal = calc_nrfinal(nr)
```

But now, the whole generator-function is a bit annoying, and I'd like to switch to ... (drumroll)

### Generator comprehensions

Defining lots of separate generator functions can be really annoying, especially when the body of the generator is quite small. There's a solution for that: generator comprehensions.

```
def f(iterable):
    for val in iterable:
        yield g(val)
k = f()
```

Can be rewritten as

```
k = (g(val) for val in iterable)
```

It even supports multiple `for`s and `if`s inside the loops.

Anyway, I disgres. What I mean is:

```
nrfinal = (re.sub(r'[0-9]+', '#', j) for j in nr)
```

And, `nrfinal` will take almost no memory at all, because all the values are evaluated just-in-time. The downside is you can not iterate twice (because it is not stored).

## Continuing in similar fashion:

Here I did the same for a couple of the pieces.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function
import os, codecs, re, string, mysql
import mysql.connector

'''Reading files with txt extension'''
y_ = ""
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/Users/Documents/source-document/part1"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            x_ = codecs.open(os.path.join(root,file),"r", "utf-8-sig")
            for lines in x_.readlines():
                y_ = y_ + lines
#print(tokenized_docs) 

'''Tokenizing sentences of the text files'''

from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
raw_docs = sent_tokenize(y_)

tokenized_docs = [sent_tokenize(y_) for sent in raw_docs]

'''Removing stop words'''

stopword_removed_sentences = []
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopset = stopwords.words("English")
for i in tokenized_docs[0]:
    tokenized_docs = ' '.join([word for word in i.split() if word not in stopset])
    stopword_removed_sentences.append(tokenized_docs)

''' Removing punctuation marks'''

regex = re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation)) 
nw = []
for review in stopword_removed_sentences:
    new_review = ''
    for token in review: 
        new_token = regex.sub(u'', token)
        if not new_token == u'':
            new_review += new_token
    nw.append(new_review)

lw = (i.lower() for i in nw)
nr = (re.sub(r'[^\[\]]+(?=\])', '#', j) for j in lw)
nrfinal = (re.sub('[0-9]+', '#', j) for j in nr)
'''Inserting into database'''
def connect():
    for j in nrfinal:
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(user = 'root', password = '', unix_socket = "/tmp/mysql.sock", database = 'Thesis' )
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO splitted_sentences(sentence_id, splitted_sentences) VALUES(%s, %s)""",(cursor.lastrowid,j))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    connect()
```

## Unnecessary looping

Here I got a bit lost, due to the double loop in `nw` and `new_review`... For this, I first need to understand the contents of `stopword_removed_sentences`. Let's look a few lines up:

```
stopword_removed_sentences = []
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopset = stopwords.words("English")
for i in tokenized_docs[0]:
    tokenized_docs = ' '.join([word for word in i.split() if word not in stopset])
    stopword_removed_sentences.append(tokenized_docs)
```

What this tells me:

- `stopwords_removed_sentences` is a list.
- The value of each of the lists is a string (`' '.join(...)` must be a list).

Ok, for now I know enough. This tells me:

- `review` is a string.
- `token` is a 1-character substring of `review`.

Looking back to the troublesome code:

```
regex = re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation)) 
nw = []
for review in stopword_removed_sentences:
    new_review = ''
    for token in review: 
        new_token = regex.sub(u'', token)
        if not new_token == u'':
            new_review += new_token
    nw.append(new_review)
```

This means we call `regex.sub` for **all** characters of `review`.

I have three different solutions:

```
new_review = regex.sub(u'', review)
```

Which reads very nice! Or

```
new_review = ''.join(token for token in review if token in string.punctuation)
```

Which is probably a bit more expensive due to the looping in Python (instead of C). Or,

```
new_review = review.translate(None, string.punctuation)
```

Which also saves us pre-compiling a regex. More readable, I think. Any are fine, but I think the `review.translate` is the easiest to look at.

Using that:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function
import os, codecs, re, string, mysql
import mysql.connector

'''Reading files with txt extension'''
y_ = ""
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/Users/Documents/source-document/part1"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            x_ = codecs.open(os.path.join(root,file),"r", "utf-8-sig")
            for lines in x_.readlines():
                y_ = y_ + lines
#print(tokenized_docs) 

'''Tokenizing sentences of the text files'''

from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
raw_docs = sent_tokenize(y_)

tokenized_docs = [sent_tokenize(y_) for sent in raw_docs]

'''Removing stop words'''

stopword_removed_sentences = []
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopset = stopwords.words("English")
for i in tokenized_docs[0]:
    tokenized_docs = ' '.join([word for word in i.split() if word not in stopset])
    stopword_removed_sentences.append(tokenized_docs)

nw = (j.translate(None, string.punctuation) for j in stopword_removed_sentences)
lw = (i.lower() for i in nw)
nr = (re.sub(r'[^\[\]]+(?=\])', '#', j) for j in lw)
nrfinal = (re.sub('[0-9]+', '#', j) for j in nr)
'''Inserting into database'''
def connect():
    for j in nrfinal:
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(user = 'root', password = '', unix_socket = "/tmp/mysql.sock", database = 'Thesis' )
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO splitted_sentences(sentence_id, splitted_sentences) VALUES(%s, %s)""",(cursor.lastrowid,j))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    connect()
```

## Quadratic run-time in the number of sentences.

Look at this code:

```
raw_docs = sent_tokenize(y_)

tokenized_docs = [sent_tokenize(y_) for sent in raw_docs]
```

First, you get the sentences from `y_`. Then, you *again* get the sentences from `y_`, but as many times as there are sentences in `y_`. Then, you only use the first item from the second set.

```
raw_docs = sent_tokenize(y_)

tokenized_docs = [sent_tokenize(y_) for sent in raw_docs]

'''Removing stop words'''

stopword_removed_sentences = []
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopset = stopwords.words("English")
for i in tokenized_docs[0]:
    tokenized_docs = ' '.join([word for word in i.split() if word not in stopset])
    stopword_removed_sentences.append(tokenized_docs)
```

Becomes

```
raw_docs = sent_tokenize(y_)

tokenized_docs = [sent_tokenize(y_) for sent in raw_docs]

'''Removing stop words'''

stopword_removed_sentences = []
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopset = stopwords.words("English")
for i in raw_docs:
    tokenized_docs = ' '.join([word for word in i.split() if word not in stopset])
    stopword_removed_sentences.append(tokenized_docs)
```

## And now switch to generators again.

But, we also want generators

```
raw_docs = sent_tokenize(y_)
stopword_removed_sentences = (' '.join(word for word in i.split() if word not in stopset) for i in raw_docs)
```

Now this becomes a bit bulky, though. The inner text is quite long. Let's make that a function.

```
def strip_stopwords(sentence):
    return ' '.join(word for word in sentence.split() if word not in stopset)

stopword_removed_sentences = (strip_stopwords(sentence) for sentence in raw_docs)
```

## Recognizing a pattern.

Now, we end up with

```
...
stopword_removed_sentences = (strip_stopwords(sentence) for sentence in raw_docs)
nw = (j.translate(None, string.punctuation) for j in stopword_removed_sentences)
lw = (i.lower() for i in nw)
nr = (re.sub(r'[^\[\]]+(?=\])', '#', j) for j in lw)
nrfinal = (re.sub('[0-9]+', '#', j) for j in nr)
...
```

Let's see if we can make that more readable...

```
actions = [
    strip_stopwords,
    lambda sentence: sentence.translate(None, string.punctuation),
    str.lower,
    lambda blob: re.sub(r'[^\[\]]+(?=\])', '#', blob),
    lambda blob: re.sub(r'[0-9]+', '#', blob),
]

def apply_all_actions(val):
    for action in actions:
        val = action(val)
    return action

nrfinal = (apply_all_actions(val) for val in raw_docs)
```

(Here we abuse the fact that `str.lower` is the same as `lambda f: f.lower()` if it is certain that `f` is a string.)

Now it is really clear that `nrfinal` is constructed from `raw_docs` by a sequence of simple transformations on the elements. If you want, you can define functions for all of the separate actions, given

```
actions = [
    strip_stopwords,
    remove_punctuation,
    lowercase,
    (some magic name, I don't know what),
    squash_numbers_to_hash,
]
```

But, this is a matter of choice.

## Connection management.

Now, for something completely different.

```
def connect():
    for j in nrfinal:
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(user = 'root', password = '', unix_socket = "/tmp/mysql.sock", database = 'Thesis' )
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO splitted_sentences(sentence_id, splitted_sentences) VALUES(%s, %s)""",(cursor.lastrowid,j))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
```

Let's read what this does:

- for every sentence in `nrfinal`, do the following:
  ** Create a connection to a mysql host.
  ** Create a cursor.
  ** Insert a value.
  ** Commit the connection.
  ** Close the connection.

Connecting is expensive. Why not do that outside the loop?

```
def connect():
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(user = 'root', password = '', unix_socket = "/tmp/mysql.sock", database = 'Thesis' )
    for j in nrfinal:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO splitted_sentences(sentence_id, splitted_sentences) VALUES(%s, %s)""",(cursor.lastrowid,j))
        conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

I'm hesitant to do this for the cursor, because that might break things. Why, you ask? Because of the `cursor.lastrowid`. Before a statement has been made, it is `None`. So we must mimic that.

```
def connect():
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(user = 'root', password = '', unix_socket = "/tmp/mysql.sock", database = 'Thesis' )
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    for j in nrfinal:
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO splitted_sentences(sentence_id, splitted_sentences) VALUES(%s, %s)""",(None,j))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

In fact, I think you want to make `sentence_id` an `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Then, write

```
def connect():
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(user = 'root', password = '', unix_socket = "/tmp/mysql.sock", database = 'Thesis' )
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    for j in nrfinal:
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO splitted_sentences(splitted_sentences) VALUES (%s)""",(j,))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

## Executing many statements

The `mysql.connector` allows `executemany`.

```
nrtuples = ((j,) for j in nrfinal)
def connect():
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(user = 'root', password = '', unix_socket = "/tmp/mysql.sock", database = 'Thesis' )
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.executemany("""INSERT INTO splitted_sentences(splitted_sentences) VALUES (%s)""", nrtuples)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

That should take care of the memory usage.

## Loading all the files

```
y_ = ""
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/Users/Documents/source-document/part1"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            x_ = codecs.open(os.path.join(root,file),"r", "utf-8-sig")
            for lines in x_.readlines():
                y_ = y_ + lines
```

You load **all** files into memory at once. This is expansive. Rather not. Let's assume that there are no cross-file sentences going on (at least I hope not!).

```
def get_sentences():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/Users/Documents/source-document/part1"):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".txt"):
                x_ = codecs.open(os.path.join(root,file),"r", "utf-8-sig")
                yield x_.read()
```

If you also know that there are no cross-line sentences, you can use

```
def get_sentences():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/Users/Documents/source-document/part1"):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".txt"):
                x_ = codecs.open(os.path.join(root,file),"r", "utf-8-sig")
                for lines in x_.readlines():
                    yield lines
```

I'm not that big a fan of this deep nesting, and would prefer to also write a generator which yields the `.txt` files. But I hope you can continue from here.

Also, maybe you should use `with codecs.open(....) as x_`, that way the file gets closed when the iteration is done.

## Further remarks.

There are certain style guidelines.

### Keep your imports at the top of the file.

- First a module-level docstring (if present).
- Then, the imports from the standard library. (preferably sorted).
- Then, imports from other libraries.
- Then, imports from other parts of the project.
- Then class/function definitions (in whatever order you please)
- Finally, only a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block. Preferably containing only a function-call to `main()` in the module.

### docstrings are no comments. Comments are no docstrings.

In the code you have `''' some useful text'''`. But you actually want to use a comment: `# some useful text`. Know to disambiguate between those.

Multi-line comments? Just start every line with `#`.

Comment: Thanks Postmus for your answer. But I think the program should be good if it is written using multiprocessing module. Will you please help me figuring out how to use the module. As i did not get better idea about using it through various tutorials.

Comment: Have you already gone through the suggested changes? That should already help a lot. Not sure if multiple processes fighting for the SQL locks would make it better.